# Moving files with rsync and custom port results in permission denied

Tags: ssh, port, rsync

I'm trying to move some files between servers with `rsync` and non-standard SSH port. I can login when I just use `ssh` and supply my password. When I try with `rsync` I get permission denied. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

This works:

```
ssh -p 1234 me@192.168.0.123
```

This doesn't:

```sh
rsync -azvhP -e "ssh -p 1234" --remove-sent-files /path/to/source/ me@192.168.0.123:/path/to/destination/

> Permission denied, please try again.
```

As a test with `scp`, this seems to work:

```
scp -rp -P 1234 /path/to/source/ me@192.168.0.123:/path/to/destination/
```

Any ideas on what's going on or how to troubleshoot?

Note: I also tried saving the options in my `~/.ssh/config`

```
Host my-server
  HostName 192.168.0.123
  Port 1234
  User me
```

Then tried to `rsync` with Host friendly name which seems to yield identical results (i.e. asks for password, then errors permission denied).

```sh
rsync path/to/source my-server:/path/to/destination
me@192.168.0.123's password:
Permission denied, please try again.
```

Answer (score 0):

You are overriding a username to log into the destination host with `me@192.168.0.123`. You need to override it in the `ssh` command too - `ssh -p 1234 -l me`

Comment: I tried as you suggested `rsync -azvhP -e "ssh -p 1234 -l me" ...` however I still get permission denied.

Comment: Check the logs on the target server.

Comment: Perhaps I'm looking at the logs incorrectly, but I only see a log entry when I purposely try an incorrect password. `User [me] from [192.168.0.123] failed to log in via [SSH] due to authorization failure.` When I use the correct password, I'll see permission denied in the terminal, but no log on the target server.

Comment: Are you using a password to authenticate? How do you pass the password to `rsync`?

Comment: Yes, I'm just using a password for authentication. Basically, after I run `rsync` in the terminal, it prompts me for the password:
`me@192.168.0.123's password:
Permission denied, please try again.` (I've updated above for more clarity)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The server I was connecting to needed the rsync service to be enabled first. I just would have thought if SSH worked rsync would too. TIL